# Creating multiple INSERT statements depending on a user value

Tags: c#, date, if-statement

When a user adds a school class to the system they choose the start and end date for the class. I have worked out how to calculate the number of days this is and store it in my database table 'Class' within the column 'TotalDayNumber'.

Currently when the user adds a class it just inserts one row into the database but I want to add the same number of rows for each individual day 'TotalDayNumber'.

E.g if the start date is 01/03/2017 - 15/03/17 - with the total number of days being 14 so I want to create 14 total rows to represent each day. 'Below is my INSERT query. I believe I require an IF statement but I don't know how to even begin it.

```
protected void insertbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int? recurrencedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRecurrence.Text);
        if (recurrencedata == 1)
        {
            int moduledata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlModule.Text);
            DateTime startdatedata = Convert.ToDateTime(txtstartdate.Text);
            DateTime enddatedata = Convert.ToDateTime(txtenddate.Text);
            int classtypedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlClassType.Text);
            int roomcodedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRoomCode.Text);
            int starttimedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartClassTime.Text);
            int endtimedata = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndClassTime.Text);

            startdatedata = DateTime.Parse(txtstartdate.Text).Date;
            enddatedata = DateTime.Parse(txtenddate.Text).Date;

            TimeSpan totaldays = enddatedata - startdatedata;

            // This is rounding the TimeSpan to the day value only
            string totalday = ((int)Math.Round(totaldays.TotalDays, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString();

            string DefaultConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DefaultConnection);

            myConnection.Open();

            string query = "INSERT INTO Class (ModuleId, ClassTypeId,  ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId, RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId, TotalDayNumber) VALUES ( @moduledata, @classtypedata, @starttimedata, @endtimedata, @roomcodedata, @startdatedata, @enddatedata,  @recurrencedata, @totaldaynumberdata)";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaldaynumberdata", totalday);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();

            SuccessPanel.Visible = true;    
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get total days as `int` and then add insert command withing `for` loop as below

```
    // add for loop 
    for(int i =0; i <= totalday; i++)
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO Class (ModuleId, ClassTypeId,  ClassScheduleStartTimeId, ClassScheduleEndTimeId, RoomCodeId, StartTime, EndTime, RecurrenceId, TotalDayNumber) VALUES ( @moduledata, @classtypedata, @starttimedata, @endtimedata, @roomcodedata, @startdatedata, @enddatedata,  @recurrencedata, @totaldaynumberdata)";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moduledata", moduledata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classtypedata", classtypedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdatedata", startdatedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddatedata", enddatedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttimedata", starttimedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomcodedata", roomcodedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtimedata", endtimedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recurrencedata", recurrencedata);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaldaynumberdata", totalday);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```